# BaseClass cannot implement interface.variable because it does not have the matching return type

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, encapsulation

***EDIT: SOLVED. I am an idiot sometimes. See my self-answer below...***

I'm working on the following C# .Net4.5 code using interfaces and polymorphism

---

```
public interface IFile
{
    List<string> Contents {get;set;}
}

public class File : IFile
{
    public List<string> Contents {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
public interface ICommandFile : IFile
{
    new List<ICommandFileLine> Contents {get;set;} /*ICommandFileLine is defined in the code as well, but I don't believe this is pertinent to the issue I am having.*/
}

public class CommandFile : File, ICommandFile
{
    public new List<ICommandFileLine> Contents {get;set;}
}
```

---

When I try and do the above, the pre-compiler complains:

> CommandFile does not implement interface memeber
>   "ICommandFile.Contents". 'File.Contents' cannot implement
>   "ICommandFile.Contents" because it does not have the matching return
>   type of "List[ICommandFileLine]"
>
> Interface member "List ICommandFile.Contents" is not
>   implemented.

I don't understand. I'm using the new keyword, surely this should indicate I wish to encapsulate the base class and define the new variable type?

Answer (score 1):

Try a generic interface -  `IFile<T>`. Then `ICommandFile` implements `IFile<CommandLine>.` Get the idea?

Answer (score 0):

An interface member implementation should not be marked 'new' )as you have in your CommandFile class), that would mean the member in the implementing class is unrelated to the member inherited from the interface.

Answer (score -1):

I realised what I did wrong not 5 minutes after posting:

List[ICommandFile] Contents *EQUALS!?* No, *{get;set;}*!

Changed:

new List[ICommandFileLine] Contents = new ListICommandFileLine;

in my local code to:

new List[ICommandFileLine] Contents {get;set;}

How embarrassing...

I'm still relatively new to implementing interfaces and making these mistakes from time to time.

Comment: If you are good enough to answer, then you are good enough to format it :)

Comment: Well I mean, I did format my OP and my reply as well as I could given the funky mark up of this site. If it matters so much to you, and since you've already proven you have the ability, be my guest.